# iOS9 upgrade SpriteKit is not displaying correctly

Tags: sprite-kit, ios9, xcode7

My app was rejected  from the appstore with the reason of not performing correctly in iOS9.

I have downloaded iOS9, and it seems that sprite textures are not performing in the order I create them (this worked well in previous versions of iOS).

Also in

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

the well known

```
for (UITouch *touch in touches) { .. }
```

loop won't detect the correct nodes. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have an issue with SKSpriteNodes and IOS9. The sprites randomly appeared or not, so I have to set in all of them the zPosition property and now I can see all of them.

Comment: Same issue here - there is a discrepancy in iOS9 that was not showing on iOS < 9 and it is the sibling order while you use ignoredSiblingOrder = YES; so I had to explicitly set all the zPosition of non-sibling SpriteTextures. This is a poor behavior.

Comment: My entire project is ruined as well, sprites only render sometimes and game code is broken..

Answer (score 0):

After testing the bug - it seems that the option of

```
for (UITouch *touch in touches) { .. }
```

Indeed no longer identifies all the nodes in touch location, but only the top most node. Which is bad for games which use it. Instead, you need to use only the following method that currently works:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:location];

for (SKNode *node in nodes) { .. }
```